# Isolation testing AR models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec

I'm trying to restructure a model spec to test it in isolation (treat ActiveRecord as a third-party), however I'm having trouble loading in my model so I can stub out the AR stuff...

So, what I had been doing was this:

**app/model/city.rb:**

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end
```

**spec/model/city_spec.rb:**

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe City do
  # ...
end
```

The default `spec_helper` loads Rails, which is what I'm trying to avoid (slow). I tried doing this:

**app/model/city.rb:**

```
require 'active_record'
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end
```

**spec/model/city_spec.rb:**

```
require 'spec_helper_lite'
describe City do
  # ...
end
```

... where `spec_helper_lite` only has `require 'pry'` in it (for debugging); it does **not** load Rails. Running a spec with this change and inspecting `City`, however, gives me two different results.

The former gives me: `City(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, name: string)`

The latter gives me: `#<ActiveRecord::Aggregations::ClassMethods:0x3fc61647de40>`

This leads to problems when I try to call something like `City.new`: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`

What do I have to do in order to load my `City` model without loading Rails so that I can stub out the AR bits?

I'm using `ruby 1.9.3` and `rails 3.1.1`.

Comment: If your still looking for an answer, check out this gist https://gist.github.com/2068977 for loading only AR and establishing a db connection

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at [mock_model](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/mocks/mock-model)?

That acts like an ActiveRecord model, but doesn't talk to the database, so will be faster.